# C# Attributes mandatory property

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I've created attribute like

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
    [Serializable]
    public class TestPropertyAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }string _name;
    }
```

and I should mark "Name" as mandatory property of this attribute. How to do it?

Comment: You could add the string name to the constructor of the attribute, but that won't stop people passing empty or null strings

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put it in the constructor instead of just as a separate property:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
[Serializable]
public class TestPropertyAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    readonly string _name;

    public TestPropertyAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

I don't believe you can make it mandatory *and* use the `Name=...` syntax when applying the attribute though.

Comment: You can still pass `null` in obviously, which would still allow an empty name

Comment: I thought about constructor but as has sad PostMan, people can set null and empty what about it problem ? Also, want to use next syntax
[TestProperty(Name = "Test",Value="TestValue")].

Comment: @jitm: Well, I'm afraid you can't avoid either of those problems. There's no way of preventing callers from using null, and there's no way of making it mandatory and using the property syntax. That's just the way it is, I'm afraid. You can always throw an exception if it's invalid, of course - but that could give an odd experience in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the System.ComponentModel.Data.Annotations.StringLength (dot.NET 4) attribute to force the min length of the string, and validate in your Data. Also, (and people will mock me for this as it's bad design usually*) i would throw an InvalidDataException("You must enter a Name in the attribute") from the ctor when Name is not filled.

The reason i would use this is because this is a design-time attribute and the exception would run as the app starts, so it would be easier to fix for the developer, this is not the best option, but I do not know how to communicate with the designer.

I have been looking on ways to communicate directly with the warnings/error in the ErrorList, but until now i have not found an easy way to do this, beside building my own custom designer or addin. I have thought alot about builing an addin that would look for an SendWarning, SendError , custom attributes, but have yet to make it happen.

as i said

```
 public sealed class TestPropertyAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(50),Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
  { 
         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new InvalidDataException("Name is a madatory property,  please fill it out not as null or string.Empty thanks"); }
       else
      _name= value;


  }
       string _name;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by Jon Skeet is a good solution. However, you can write this with shorter code nowadays. It works the same:

```
public class TestPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestPropertyAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2024, so let's make it even shorter :)

```
public class TestPropertyAttribute(string name) : Attribute
{
    public string Name => name;
}
```