# Making a property compulsory

Tags: c#, properties

Is there any way to make a property that is defined in a class compulsory?
  I want the compiler to complain if the object is declared and used without the compulsory property.

Comment: What do you mean by 'used without'?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607087/c-attributes-mandatory-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way might be to implement a constructor that forces the creation of an object to have an initial value for a property:

```
class Demo
{
    public int P {get; set;}

    Demo(int p)
    {
        P = p;
    }
}
```

Now the client can only create the object by passing a value for p:

```
var d = new Demo(42);
```

Comment: Thanks I did exactly this without seeing your solution: great minds and all that!. upvoted too.

Comment: If it is the answer to your question please mark it as the answer (not just upvoting)

Answer (score 6):

Best approach I would think would be to not specify a default constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string myProp)
    {
        MyProp = myProp;
    }

    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a constructor to the class that would take a value for the property?

```
public class MyClass 
{     
   public int Mandatory {get; set;}
   public int Optional {get; set;}

   public MyClass(int mandatory)
   {
      Mandatory = mandatory;
   }

   public MyClass(int mandatory, int optional)
   {
      Mandatory = mandatory;
      Optional = optional;
   }
}
```

This way, the class can be instantiated using either the one or two-parameter constructor, so the user will have to specify a value for the `Mandatory` property.

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();   // does not compile
MyClass x = new MyClass(1);  //Mandatory = 1; Optional = 0 (default value)
MyClass x = new MyClass(1,2);//Mandatory = 1; Optional = 2
```

Comment: +1 for making the difference between required and optional values explicit. However, note that with C#4 we can now save a lot of overloads with the use of default argument values :P

Comment: @herenvardo: I did not want to muddy the watters even more with optional arguments, but yes, that could eliminate the need for two constructors.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't force somebody to provide information to a property.

However, you can go the normal route, and make the constructor require the information. That way, the object can't be constructed without providing the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a constructor to your class that accepts one parameter - the value for your property. Like this, the property is always initialized after an instance of the class is created.

Answer (score 1):

make default constructor private and define constructor that will get needed value for your property

```
public YourClass(string value)
{
   YourCompulsaryProperty = value;
}

public string YourCompulsaryProperty{get; set;}
```

Comment: you don't need to make the default constructor private - the moment you declare a constructor yourself the default constructor isn't there anymore.

Comment: Yes but if he do have default constructor whith some logic in it,then should make it private