# How do I make a property mandatory on a custom user control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2005, controls

I have a custom control and would like the properties to be mandatory (not default) when a programmer codes the control. Is there a good way to do this without throwing exceptions in the program?

Comment: Define them in an interface which the control will have to implement.

Comment: You want them to be required when using or deriving from the control?

Comment: @JaredPar    Yes. I want it to be required when deriving from the control.

Comment: @esquire why don't abstract properties work for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the mandatory fields in constructor define only 'get' property against it.
That's what Jon Skeet the great says about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607087/c-sharp-attributes-mandatory-property) :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a smart-tag panel using a custom designer. Maybe this will help someone else...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171829.aspx